# problemas al publicar un sitio asp.net y OWIN

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web.config, owin

desarrolle un sitio en Visual Studio 2019, lo he bajado hace poco y como no soy muy experto utilizo las plantillas q trae por defecto. 
Tengo un windows server 2016.
He instalado el IIS de manera basica

Resulta, que como todo es nuevo, aparentemente hay nuevas características que no conzco, como por ejemplo la de OWIN, que trajo por defecto la plantilla que utilice para desarrollar. Cuando corro el sitio web desde el visual studio funciona correctamente, pero cuando intento hacer el deploy en el servidor y correrlo me tira la siguiente pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo muchos hilos y aparentemente es algo que tiene que ver con el OWIN, pero no puedo econtrar la solucíon. Ya que toque lo que toque en el webconfig se rompe y no reconoce. 
He probado comentando esas

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
     </modules>  
 </system.webServer>
```

pero no resulto,tambien probe cambiar el item authenticationForms= "None"  a "Forms" pero tampoco funcionó.

Algun comentario que me pueda guiar?

Saludos

Comment: Los pasos que seguí fueron los que se hace por default, publique en una carpeta y lo puse en la carpeta inetpub/wwwroot/. Luego, en IIS habilite el las caracteristicas de ASP.Net, y la de seguridad... no se que mas podria decirte

Answer (score 1):

Luego de buscar mucho encontre la solucion: la solucion esta en este hilo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path/12867753#12867753

y consta en lo siguiente con la pequeña diferencia que en vez de application Settings busque la seccion "Modules" que es lo que me dice el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]